# Finding multiple common starting strings

Tags: python, algorithm

I have a list of strings in which one or more subsets of the strings have a common starting string. I would like a function that takes as input the original list of strings and returns a list of all the common starting strings. In my particular case I also know that each common prefix must end in a given delimiter. Below is an example of the type of input data I am talking about (ignore any color highlighting):

> ```
> Population of metro area / Portland
> Population of city / Portland
> Population of metro area / San Francisco
> Population of city / San Francisco
> Population of metro area / Seattle
> Population of city / Seattle
> ```

Here the delimiter is `/` and the common starting strings are `Population of metro area` and `Population of city`. Perhaps the delimiter won't ultimately matter but I've put it in to emphasize that I don't want just one result coming back, namely the universal common starting string `Population of`; nor do I want the common substrings `Population of metro area / S` and `Population of city / S`.

The ultimate use for this algorithm will be to group the strings by their common prefixes. For instance, the list above can be restructured into a hierarchy that eliminates redundant information, like so:

> ```
> Population of metro area
>     Portland
>     San Francisco
>     Seattle
> Population of city
>     Portland
>     San Francisco
>     Seattle
> ```

I'm using Python but pseudo-code in any language would be fine.

**EDIT**
As noted by Tom Anderson, the original problem as given can easily be reduced to simply splitting the strings and using a hash to group by the prefix. I had originally thought the problem might be more complicated because sometimes in practice I encounter prefixes with embedded delimiters, but I realize this could also be solved by simply doing a right split that is limited to splitting only one time.

Comment: How do you want to handle "San Francisco" and "San Antonio" in your grouping?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Isn't this just looping over the strings, splitting them on the delimiter, then grouping the second halves by the first halves? Like so:

```
def groupByPrefix(strings):
    stringsByPrefix = {}
    for string in strings:
            prefix, suffix = map(str.strip, string.split("/", 1))
            group = stringsByPrefix.setdefault(prefix, [])
            group.append(suffix)
    return stringsByPrefix
```

In general, if you're looking for string prefices, the solution would be to whop the strings into a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie). Any branch node with multiple children is a maximal common prefix. But your need is more restricted than that.

Comment: Why this over `itertools.groupby`?

Answer (score 5):

```
d = collections.defaultdict(list)

for place, name in ((i.strip() for i in line.split('/'))
                    for line in text.splitlines()):
    d[place].append(name)
```

so `d` will be a dict like:

```
{'Population of city':
       ['Portland',
        'San Francisco',
        'Seattle'],
 'Population of metro area':
       ['Portland',
        'San Francisco',
        'Seattle']}
```

---

You can replace `(i.strip() for i in line.split('/')` by `line.split(' / ')` if you know there's no extra whitespace around your text.

Answer (score 3):

Using `csv.reader` and `itertools.groupby`, treat the '/' as the delimiter and group by the first column:

```
for key, group in groupby(sorted(reader(inp, delimiter='/')), key=lambda x: x[0]):
    print key
    for line in group:
        print "\t", line[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't very general, but may do what you need:

```
def commons(strings):
    return set(s.split(' / ')[0] for s in strings)
```

And to avoid going back over the data for the grouping:

```
def group(strings):
    groups = {}
    for s in strings:
        prefix, remainder = s.split(' / ', 1)
        groups.setdefault(prefix, []).append(remainder)
    return groups
```